# Algoritmo en PHP ( Calcular la menor fecha entre dos items de un mismo array multidimensional)

Tags: php, algoritmos

tengo un problema y hace tres dias me estoy rompiendo la cabeza. Quiero obtener la menor fecha de cada item de este array:
Es decir necesito calcular la menor fecha entre dos items de un mismo array multidimensional, en este caso seria entre dos clientes distintos, que a su vez tienen items con fechas distintas.

```
Ejemplo: ITEM1['cliente Juan']['fecha'] > ITEM1['cliente Florencia']['fecha'] = true

^ array:2 [
  0 => array:11 [
    "cliente" => 11
    "nombrecliente" => "cliente Juan"
    "items" => array:2 [
      0 => array:13 [
        "id" => 333
        "nombre" => "ITEM 1"    
        "cantidad" => "12"
        "fecha" => "8"
        "subtotal" => 144
      ]
      1 => array:13 [
        "id" => 334
        "nombre" => "ITEM 2"
        "cantidad" => "14"
        "fecha" => "2"
        "subtotal" => 196
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:11 [
    "cliente" => 12
    "nombrecliente" => "cliente Florencia"
    "items" => array:2 [
      0 => array:13 [
        "id" => 333
        "nombre" => "ITEM 1"
        "cantidad" => "12"
        "fecha" => "10"
        "subtotal" => 144
      ]
      1 => array:13 [
        "id" => 334
        "nombre" => "ITEM 2"
        "cantidad" => "14"
        "fecha" => "11"
        "subtotal" => 196
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

El codigo que mas se acerca al resultado es este: Pero si ustedes obserban el contador $i aumenta de 0 a 1 y $d de 1 a 1 ( ya que son dos clientes 0,1). El que me estaria complicando la comparacion es $i. Creo no tener que explicarle mas del funcionamiento del script.

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        for($d=1;$d<count($array);$d++){
            if($array[$i]['items'][$i]['fecha']<$array[$d]['items'][$i]['fecha']){
                $array[$i]['items'][$i]['menor_fecha'] = true;
            }else{
                $array[$d]['items'][$i]['menor_fecha'] = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: Por favor, podrías [edit] tu pregunta ya agregar el código que has intentando, como así tambien el resultado esperado.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. Lo que necesitas es obtener el valor de fecha menor del primer cliente y compararlo con el menor del segundo cliente ???

Comment: Asi es @SistemasSinZanjas.. Quiero comprar la fecha de cada items diferenciado por cliente y para obtener la meno fecha.

Comment: por curiosidad, el campo "fecha" tiene valores numericos enteros o es solo un ejemplo rapido? Lo digo porque una cosa es comparar numeros y otra comparar fechas...

Comment: Este me imagino es un ejemplo de prueba, pero ¿En la practica real habría mas items y mas clientes?

Comment: @SistemasSinZanjas edite el articulo, esta muy bien el ejemplo que planteas pero la comparacion es entre dos items distintos de clientes distintos: Es decir necesito calcular la menor fecha entre dos items de un mismo array multidimensional, en este caso seria entre dos clientes distintos, que a su vez tienen items con fechas distintas. Ejemplo: ´Ejemplo: ITEM1['cliente Juan']['fecha'] > ITEM1['cliente Florencia']['fecha'] = true´

Comment: @Jakala los dos son enteros

Comment: @SistemasSinZanjas Claro, la idea es qie sean muchos mas clientes y productos (items)

Comment: @NahuelJakobson Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta espero te ayude con tu problema, solo que si me confunde bastante el planteamiento de tu pregunta. 
Por lo que te pregunto ¿Lo que necesitas saber es que cliente tiene la menor fecha ?

Comment: @SistemasSinZanjas exacto! Necesito saber cual de los clientes, comprandolos, tiene la menor fecha. Por ejemplo: El ITEM 1 de cliente 11 tiene fecha 8 y el ITEM 1 del cliente 12 tiene fecha 10, entonces el cliente 11 en el ITEM 1 tiene la menor fecha.

Answer (score 2):

Traté de construir una estructura de datos que se asemejara a lo que has plasmado en tu pregunta. Quedaría algo similar a esto:

```
$array = array (
    0 => array (
        "cliente" => 11,
        "nombrecliente" => "cliente Juan",
        "items" => array (
            0 => array (
                "id" => 333,
                "nombre" => "ITEM 1",
                "cantidad" => "12",
                "fecha" => "8",
                "subtotal" => 144
              ),
            1 => array (
                "id" => 334,
                "nombre" => "ITEM 2",
                "cantidad" => "14",
                "fecha" => "2",
                "subtotal" => 196
            )
        )       
    ),
    1 => array (
        "cliente" => 12,
        "nombrecliente" => "cliente Florencia",
        "items" => array (
            0 => array (
                "id" => 333,
                "nombre" => "ITEM 1",
                "cantidad" => "12",
                "fecha" => "10",
                "subtotal" => 144
              ),
            1 => array (
                "id" => 334,
                "nombre" => "ITEM 2",
                "cantidad" => "14",
                "fecha" => "11",
                "subtotal" => 196
            )
        )       
    )
);
```

Luego, el truco para saber como moverte por un `array` es fijarte en los índices:

Primero tienes un `array` con dos elementos, (índices: 0, 1), cada uno de ellos tiene 3 elementos (índices: 'cliente, 'nombrecliente', 'items') el índice 'items' es un `array` con dos elementos elementos (índices: 0, 1) y cada uno de ellos tiene 5 elementos (índices: 'id', 'nombre', 'cantidad', 'fecha', 'subtotal').

Por ello, para poder hacer la comparación que necesitas, deberías hacer algo como esto:

```
$items_cliente = array();

//Recorremos los clientes
foreach($array as $cliente) {
    //Añadimos al array un índice que sea el ID del cliente.
    $items_cliente[$cliente['cliente']] = '';
    //Preparamos el array que contendrá las fechas del cliente
    $fechas_items_cliente = array();

    //Recorremos cada fecha para insertarla en el array
    foreach ($cliente['items'] as $item) {
        array_push($fechas_items_cliente, $item['fecha']);
    }

    //Almacenamos en la clave del cliente de $items_cliente la fecha
    // más pequeña.
    $items_cliente[$cliente['cliente']] = min($fechas_items_cliente);
}

var_dump($items_cliente);
```

**Salida**

```
array(2) { [11]=> string(1) "2" [12]=> string(2) "10" }
```

De esta manera tendríamos almacenado en el array la fecha más pequeña del cliente asociada al ID del cliente.

Answer (score 2):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Me confunde mucho el planteamiento de tu pregunta sin embargo si lo que quieres es hacer la comparación de solo esos dos elementos dentro de tu ITEM puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<?php
    $ITEM = [
        [
            "cliente" => 11,
            "nombrecliente" => "cliente Juan",
            "items" => [
                [
                    "id" => 333,
                    "nombre" => "ITEM 1", 
                    "cantidad" => "12",
                    "fecha" => "8",
                    "subtotal" => 144,
                ],
                [
                    "id" => 334,
                    "nombre" => "ITEM 2",
                    "cantidad" => "14",
                    "fecha" => "2",
                    "subtotal" => 196,
                ],
            ]
        ],

        [
            "cliente" => 12,
            "nombrecliente" => "cliente Florencia",
            "items" => [
                [
                    "id" => 333,
                    "nombre" => "ITEM 1",
                    "cantidad" => "12",
                    "fecha" => "10",
                    "subtotal" => 144,
                ],
                [
                    "id" => 334,
                    "nombre" => "ITEM 2",
                    "cantidad" => "14",
                    "fecha" => "11",
                    "subtotal" => 196,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

    function obtenerMenorFecha($cliente) {
        $fechas = [];

        foreach ($cliente['items'] as $datos) {
            array_push($fechas, $datos['fecha']);
        }
        return min($fechas);
    }

    function esMayor($item1, $item2) {
        $fecha1 = obtenerMenorFecha($item1);
        $fecha2 = obtenerMenorFecha($item2);

        if ($fecha1 > $fecha2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    echo var_dump(esMayor($ITEM[0], $ITEM[1]));
?>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda mi respuesta

Reitero una vez más si no es lo que buscas con gusto te puedo ayudar a encontrar una mejor respuesta.